# JS: using try/catch with more than one await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I want to make a fetch request to an API and potentially catch the error using a try/catch.  After I `await` the fetch, I `await` the response `text()`.  This should never have an error .  Is there a better way of writing this without both `await`'s being inside the try/catch?

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers, body });
    const responseText = await response.text();
    
    if (responseText) {
        const a = responseText.split("<svg")[1].split("</svg>")[0]
        const svg = "<svg" + a + "</svg>";
        const blob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});


        return blob;
    }  
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error('Returned error:' + e);
}
```

Comment: Why would having both `await`s in the `try` block be a problem?

Comment: not necessarily a problem but just to make it clear that the "catch" is related to only the first await.

Comment: By the way, your `catch` seems useless, it's actually causing information to be lost about the previous error such as its stack because you coerce it into a string. If all you do in your `catch` is rethrowing the error, you could simply remove the whole `try` block.

Comment: if you want to specifically handle errors in the `response` assignment line, you can do `let response; try { response = await fetch(...) } catch (e) { ... }`

Answer (score -2):

you can use promise instead , example

```js
doSomething()
.then(function(result) {
  return doSomethingElse(result);
})
.then(function(newResult) {
  return doThirdThing(newResult);
})
.then(function(finalResult) {
  console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
})
.catch(failureCallback);
```

read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: that's really not a cleaner solution though